# Sample code "FragmentBasic" from developer.android.com not working as it should

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to run sample code from: [developer.android.com/fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

On smartphone it works fine, but on tablets crashes.

The problem is in `ArticleFragment.java` in lines:

```
public void updateArticleView(int position) {
    TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
    article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);
}
```

Method `getActivity()` returns proper activity, but `findViewById` returns `null` on large screens, so app crashes trying to call `setText()` on `null`.

Can someone give any hint why on freshly downloaded source is such error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround:

1) change code in `onCreateView()` from:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
```

to:

```
View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
article = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.article_text);
return myFragmentView;
```

2) delete from `updateArticleView()`:

```
TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
```

3) add field:

```
TextView article;
```

Comment: I also encountered this issue while going over the "Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments" section in Android Developers Training (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) and concluded that the code is buggy on tablets with large layouts. I think its better to use the Fragments API Guides for learning (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)